# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (52,1) into shape (52)

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry if this is a silly question but I am not at all experienced with Python and I need this for a project. I initialise my residuals matrix (which are every time equal to 52x1) with the number of columns I need in each iteration. Then when I try to say that for example the first column I need to be a specific array (which is always 52x1) I get this error.

```
for t in np.arange(52,dec.shape[0]):
    res = np.full((52,pd.qcut(mom.values[t],10, duplicates='drop').value_counts().iloc[-1]), np.nan)  
#     print(np.shape(res))
    w = -1
    for j in np.argwhere(dec.values[t] == pd.qcut(mom.values[t],10, duplicates='drop').categories.max()):
        ret = rt.values[t-52:t,j]
        factors = fama.values[t-52:t,:]
        if (np.isnan(ret).any() == False):           
            Y = ret
            X = np.hstack((np.ones((52,1)), factors))

            betas = np.linalg.lstsq(X,Y,rcond=None)[0]
            
            res[:,w+1] = (Y - X.dot(betas))
```

Comment: `res` is 2d, so `res[:,w+1]` is 1d.  **You don't say** but my guess it's this assignment that's giving the error.  A (52,) or (1,52) shape can be placed in a (52,) shape slot, but a (52,1) cannot.  This a subcase of `numpy` broadcasting.

Comment: yeath thanks I actually did .reshape(52,) and it worked! (:

Answer (score 0):

For NumPy there's a difference between an array, or a "table with 1 column". Those are the shape (52) and (52, 1)  the error mentions.

See [this page from the NumPy user guide](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for details. You'll need to reshape before doing the operation.

Comment: but my initial array is 52xN and everytime I try to put as a new column a 52x1 array...

Comment: for some reason if I flatten() my 52x1 array I get NaNs in some position whereas the initial array did not have any